browser.getGeoLocation() is not working webdriver io
http://v4.webdriver.io/api/mobile/getGeoLocation.html
As for the above documentation, there is a method to get Geo locations when doing mobile automation.
But when I use it in my automation code, I'm getting an error.
driver.getGeoLocation is not a function

var location = browser.getGeoLocation()

So is there any way to use above getGeoLocation() method in my code to retrieve the geo coordinates.
As an alternative, I'm using  await axios.get('https://ipinfo.io/loc');

The one who set Down vote know the answer ?
